# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value with "loadHTMLString" in a webview

Tags: ios, swift

I try to load a simple HTML Page into a webview. There are several samples out there, but it doesn't work for me. What am I doing wrong ?

My Error at myWebView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil):

```
unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Here's my Code:

```
class myClass: UIViewController {
      @IBOutlet weak var myWebView: UIWebView!





    override func viewDidLoad() {

myWebView = UIWebView(frame: self.view.frame);

      var htmlString:String! = "<br /><h2>Hello Page</h2>"
            //var nullvalue:NSURL=NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "")!;
            myWebView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
```

Comment: Why are you initializing in `viewDidLoad` if you have an `@IBOutlet`?

Comment: There no real reason for it. I am just trying all combinations, because I do not find any  simple sample. Is there any sample out there ? I just want to say Hello on a UIWebview without loading a page.

Comment: Thanks a lot Aaron. "Why are you initializing in viewDidLoad if you have an @IBOutlet" ? This was the right questions. defined as "var myWebView: UIWebView!" it works. Simple a sequence of missunderstandings from my side :-) Solved !

Comment: Great to hear. Please mark my answer as correct so other viewers will know your issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

1. `myWebView` may be `nil` if your outlet is disconnected or you set it to `nil`.
2. The `baseURL` argument of `loadHTMLString(_:baseURL:)` is of type `NSURL!`, which is not optional. Despite all the Objective-C code out there to the contrary, this means you must pass it an `NSURL` object.

Comment: I added some missing code. myWebView is initialized in viewDidLoad(). Is there any simple sample out there, because I don't get it to work. All simples found call "loadHTMLString " with parameter "baseURL: nil".